# SimpleDateFormat setTimeZone not working if phone timezone has changed

Tags: java, android, timezone, jodatime

I'm encountering a weird issue while working with SimpleDateFormat and timezones.

Basically, I have this code snippet:

```
    String input              = "2017-12-21 16:15:00";
    String inputTZ            = "America/Los_Angeles";
    String phoneTZ            = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
    SimpleDateFormat fmtInput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    fmtInput.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(inputTZ));

    SimpleDateFormat fmtOutputEventTZ = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    fmtOutputEventTZ.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(inputTZ));

    SimpleDateFormat fmtOutputPhoneTZ = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    fmtOutputPhoneTZ.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(phoneTZ));


    try {
        LocalDateTime dt = new LocalDateTime(fmtInput.parse(input));

        Log.d("DEBUG>>>>", "INPUT=" + input);
        Log.d("DEBUG>>>>", "TZ_EVENT=" + inputTZ);
        Log.d("DEBUG>>>>", "TZ_PHONE=" + phoneTZ);
        Log.d("DEBUG>>>>", "DT=" + dt);
        Log.d("DEBUG>>>>", "OUTPUT_EVENT=" + fmtOutputEventTZ.format(dt.toDate()));
        Log.d("DEBUG>>>>", "OUTPUT_PHONE=" + fmtOutputPhoneTZ.format(dt.toDate()));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code logic is as follow:

- I have an input date with Los Angeles timezone (GMT-8)
- I parse this date specifying the timezone (LA)
- Then I format the date using the original timezone (LA) and the current phone timezone

I run the code with my phone timezone set to Chicago (GMT-6) and got the following output.

```
D/DEBUG>>>>: INPUT=2017-12-21 16:15:00
D/DEBUG>>>>: TZ_EVENT=America/Los_Angeles
D/DEBUG>>>>: TZ_PHONE=America/Chicago
D/DEBUG>>>>: DT=2017-12-21T18:15:00.000
D/DEBUG>>>>: OUTPUT_EVENT=2017-12-21 16:15:00
D/DEBUG>>>>: OUTPUT_PHONE=2017-12-21 18:15:00
```

Basically, the result is what was expected.

However, if I change my phone timezone to be that of New York (GMT-5) without restarting the app, I got the following output

```
D/DEBUG>>>>: INPUT=2017-12-21 16:15:00
D/DEBUG>>>>: TZ_EVENT=America/Los_Angeles
D/DEBUG>>>>: TZ_PHONE=America/New_York
D/DEBUG>>>>: DT=2017-12-21T18:15:00.000
D/DEBUG>>>>: OUTPUT_EVENT=2017-12-21 15:15:00
D/DEBUG>>>>: OUTPUT_PHONE=2017-12-21 18:15:00
```

Notice that the timezone returned by `TimeZone.getDefault().getID()` is the right one, but when it is parsed, SimpleDateFormat convert it as if the phone time zone was still Chicago, thus returning the wrong time!

However, if I kill the app and restart it, the same code works fine:

```
D/DEBUG>>>>: INPUT=2017-12-21 16:15:00
D/DEBUG>>>>: TZ_EVENT=America/Los_Angeles
D/DEBUG>>>>: TZ_PHONE=America/New_York
D/DEBUG>>>>: DT=2017-12-21T19:15:00.000
D/DEBUG>>>>: OUTPUT_EVENT=2017-12-21 16:15:00
D/DEBUG>>>>: OUTPUT_PHONE=2017-12-21 19:15:00
```

From my understanding, `SimpleDateFormat.parse` parse the date and store it as the number of seconds since 1970. Using `setTimeZone` should use the timezone to shift the time appropriately.

However, seems like the phone timezone change is not reflected by SimpleDateFormat while `TimeZone.getDefault().getID()` clearly reflects the change.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution!

I called `DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID(TimeZone.getDefault().getID()))` at the very beginning.

I guess `DateTimeZone.setDefault` is called when the application is started but never reset afterward by joda-time itself, even though the timezone of the user might have changed.

Comment: What you have observed is the expected behavior.  The JVM has its own time zone setting, which may be different from the device time zone setting. If you don’t do anything to set it, it will be initialized to the device setting when the JVM is launched. After that it doesn’t change automagically, but one way (and a good way) of changing it is through Joda-Time (when already using this library).